# getting an element's EventListeners

Tags: javascript, firebug, addeventlistener, inspect

In safari's (and chrome's) element inspector there's an "Event Listeners" section (in the right frame of the elements tab) that show's the Event Listeners in the document. Is there anything similar in firebug? Also, is it possible to get an element's event listeners using javascript (like `elmnt.onclick`, but should work for events added with `addEventListener()` as well)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available for firebug:

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Extensions#Eventbug

For your second question, is it possible to get the events added via addEventListener in javascript? Generally it is not. That add-on uses `eventlistenerservice` you would need elevated privileges, a signed script and it would still only work in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks!                                                               And the other question?